# `showticklabels = FALSE` in `plotly::layout()` fails with multiple subplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Take the following ["Horizontal grid" example from the Plotly ggplot2 Library](https://plot.ly/ggplot2/facet_grid/)

I want to omit the labels from the X axes in both subplots, like:

[image]

The way to do this should be, allegedly, by using the `layout()` function and including configuration parameter `xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE)`.  See however the output in the following reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex)

ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE))
```

[image]

As you can see, only the first subplot is affected.

I have already tried by rendering each subplot as a plotly object, and then using the subplot function:

```
tips %>% group_split(sex) %>% map(
  ~{
    p <- ggplot(., aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) + geom_point(shape=1)
    ggplotly(p)
  }
) %>%
  subplot(shareY = TRUE) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE))
```

The result is the same.

Also, calling `layout(., xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE))` for each subplot individually fails, as `subplot()` apparently overrides the layout of the subplots.

Additionally, inspection of the JSON object seems to show that only one layout attribute is generated for the whole subplot, which I understand should control the properties of all subplots.

Any idea on how to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you desire, removing all x-axis labels from the ticks, I would remove them using your `ggplot` theme. Thus before you call `ggplotly`

```
p <- ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, y=tip/total_bill)) +
        geom_point(shape=1) +
        facet_grid(. ~ sex) + 
        theme( axis.text.x=element_blank()) # remove x-labels
p 

ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Superb! Actually, I had tried adding a `scale_x_continuous(labels = NULL)`, which did not translate properly to `plot.ly`, but this one works perfectly.